# How build EXE from TornadoFX JAR?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, exe, tornadofx

I have a simple JavaFX/TornadoFX project on Windows that builds in a JAR and runs correctly from under IntelliJ IDEA and in the JRE installed on my computer. I want to make it so that this project can run on any Windows machine without JRE installed. To do this, in IntelliJ, I created an artifact "JavaFx application" and configured it as it is written in the instructions for TornadoFX.

[project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkm9p.png)

[project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFrZn.png)

The executable file builds successfully, but when I try to run it I get the error "No method main in class com/example/demo/app/MyApp."

I tried to add main to the project code, as it is written in the instructions for TornadoFX, but I cannot specify this method in the project settings.

[project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obZqH.png)

Only the MyApp class can be added automatically, but of course it does not contain the main method.

[project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Voty8.png)

What am I doing wrong and how can I make an executable file under Windows?

My code in MyApp.kt:

```
package com.example.demo.app

import com.example.demo.view.MainView
import tornadofx.App
import tornadofx.launch

class MyApp: App(MainView::class, Styles::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that JavaPackager does not add the JRE distribution to the executable. I want users without JRE installed to be able to run my application without any extra steps.

If the user already has JRE installed, then he can immediately launch *.jar, and it does not need to be masked as *.exe.

IntellyJ creates a distribution kit that installs the JRE by launching the application. And everything would be fine, but I had a problem described this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I carefully re-read the manual for TornadoFx and saw the important phrase: "Notice the Kt at the end.". Thus, in the project settings in the Application class field, you need to add "Kt" by hand. I did it and it worked out as I wish.